# Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with inline CSS

Tags: css, html, placeholder

Reading the SO posting "[Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)" I think I understand how to do it with an external CSS.

Even after searching through Google and SO I found no way to make this also work with *inline CSS* (I'm aware that inline CSS should be avoided).

E.g. something like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter something" style="???" />
```

For the `???` part I have no idea what to enter in order to change the color of the placeholder text.

**So my question is:**

Is it possible to use inline CSS to change the color of a placeholder text? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, you certainly cannot. But you can do this with css

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #fff;
}
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #fff;
}
input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #fff;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what [the linked article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css) also suggest, right?

Comment: Yep thats the same :D